# Can't locate the GET request

Tags: web-scraping, get, xmlhttprequest, httprequest, google-chrome-devtools

Here's the page I'm looking at: http://beta.fortune.com/fortune500/walmart-1

The only relevant XHR that I see under Chrome Dev Tools Network tab is this: http://fortune.com/api/v2/company/wmt/expand/1

But the response to that doesn't contain all the data of the page, only the pricing data. I've been trying to locate the request being made for the data you see at the top of the page on black background (Previous Rank, Revenues ($M), Rev Change, etc.). What's the GET request for this data? Or are those fields being populated in some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a closer look at the webpage source code (XHR response from http://beta.fortune.com/fortune500/walmart-1), you will see the following HTML fragment (I just beautified it to make more clear):

```html
<div data-reactid=".16d1cbmhnfi.1.0.4.1:1.3.1.0.0.0">
    <div class="ranking-slide brand-revenue-slide" data-reactid=".16d1cbmhnfi.1.0.4.1:1.3.1.0.0.0.$slide-Previous Rank" style="transform:translateX(0px);-webkit-transform:translateX(0px);">
        <a class="ranking-caption" data-reactid=".16d1cbmhnfi.1.0.4.1:1.3.1.0.0.0.$slide-Previous Rank.0"><span class="title" data-reactid=".16d1cbmhnfi.1.0.4.1:1.3.1.0.0.0.$slide-Previous Rank.0.0">Previous Rank</span><span class="data" data-reactid=".16d1cbmhnfi.1.0.4.1:1.3.1.0.0.0.$slide-Previous Rank.0.1">1</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="ranking-slide brand-revenue-slide" data-reactid=".16d1cbmhnfi.1.0.4.1:1.3.1.0.0.0.$slide-Revenues ($M)" style="transform:translateX(0px);-webkit-transform:translateX(0px);">
        <a class="ranking-caption" data-reactid=".16d1cbmhnfi.1.0.4.1:1.3.1.0.0.0.$slide-Revenues ($M).0"><span class="title" data-reactid=".16d1cbmhnfi.1.0.4.1:1.3.1.0.0.0.$slide-Revenues ($M).0.0">Revenues ($M)</span><span class="data" data-reactid=".16d1cbmhnfi.1.0.4.1:1.3.1.0.0.0.$slide-Revenues ($M).0.1">$482,130</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="ranking-slide brand-revenue-slide" data-reactid=".16d1cbmhnfi.1.0.4.1:1.3.1.0.0.0.$slide-Rev Change" style="transform:translateX(0px);-webkit-transform:translateX(0px);">
        <a class="ranking-caption" data-reactid=".16d1cbmhnfi.1.0.4.1:1.3.1.0.0.0.$slide-Rev Change.0"><span class="title" data-reactid=".16d1cbmhnfi.1.0.4.1:1.3.1.0.0.0.$slide-Rev Change.0.0">Rev Change</span><span class="data" data-reactid=".16d1cbmhnfi.1.0.4.1:1.3.1.0.0.0.$slide-Rev Change.0.1">-0.7%</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="ranking-slide brand-revenue-slide" data-reactid=".16d1cbmhnfi.1.0.4.1:1.3.1.0.0.0.$slide-Profits ($M)" style="transform:translateX(0px);-webkit-transform:translateX(0px);">
        <a class="ranking-caption" data-reactid=".16d1cbmhnfi.1.0.4.1:1.3.1.0.0.0.$slide-Profits ($M).0"><span class="title" data-reactid=".16d1cbmhnfi.1.0.4.1:1.3.1.0.0.0.$slide-Profits ($M).0.0">Profits ($M)</span><span class="data" data-reactid=".16d1cbmhnfi.1.0.4.1:1.3.1.0.0.0.$slide-Profits ($M).0.1">$14,694</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="ranking-slide brand-revenue-slide" data-reactid=".16d1cbmhnfi.1.0.4.1:1.3.1.0.0.0.$slide-Profit Change" style="transform:translateX(0px);-webkit-transform:translateX(0px);">
        <a class="ranking-caption" data-reactid=".16d1cbmhnfi.1.0.4.1:1.3.1.0.0.0.$slide-Profit Change.0"><span class="title" data-reactid=".16d1cbmhnfi.1.0.4.1:1.3.1.0.0.0.$slide-Profit Change.0.0">Profit Change</span><span class="data" data-reactid=".16d1cbmhnfi.1.0.4.1:1.3.1.0.0.0.$slide-Profit Change.0.1">-10.2%</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="ranking-slide brand-revenue-slide" data-reactid=".16d1cbmhnfi.1.0.4.1:1.3.1.0.0.0.$slide-Assets ($M)" style="transform:translateX(0px);-webkit-transform:translateX(0px);">
        <a class="ranking-caption" data-reactid=".16d1cbmhnfi.1.0.4.1:1.3.1.0.0.0.$slide-Assets ($M).0"><span class="title" data-reactid=".16d1cbmhnfi.1.0.4.1:1.3.1.0.0.0.$slide-Assets ($M).0.0">Assets ($M)</span><span class="data" data-reactid=".16d1cbmhnfi.1.0.4.1:1.3.1.0.0.0.$slide-Assets ($M).0.1">$199,581</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="ranking-slide brand-revenue-slide" data-reactid=".16d1cbmhnfi.1.0.4.1:1.3.1.0.0.0.$slide-Employees" style="transform:translateX(0px);-webkit-transform:translateX(0px);">
        <a class="ranking-caption" data-reactid=".16d1cbmhnfi.1.0.4.1:1.3.1.0.0.0.$slide-Employees.0"><span class="title" data-reactid=".16d1cbmhnfi.1.0.4.1:1.3.1.0.0.0.$slide-Employees.0.0">Employees</span><span class="data" data-reactid=".16d1cbmhnfi.1.0.4.1:1.3.1.0.0.0.$slide-Employees.0.1">2,300,000</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="ranking-slide brand-revenue-slide" data-reactid=".16d1cbmhnfi.1.0.4.1:1.3.1.0.0.0.$slide-Mkt Value as of 3/31/16 ($M)" style="transform:translateX(0px);-webkit-transform:translateX(0px);">
        <a class="ranking-caption" data-reactid=".16d1cbmhnfi.1.0.4.1:1.3.1.0.0.0.$slide-Mkt Value as of 3/31/16 ($M).0"><span class="title" data-reactid=".16d1cbmhnfi.1.0.4.1:1.3.1.0.0.0.$slide-Mkt Value as of 3/31/16 ($M).0.0">Mkt Value as of 3/31/16 ($M)</span><span class="data" data-reactid=".16d1cbmhnfi.1.0.4.1:1.3.1.0.0.0.$slide-Mkt Value as of 3/31/16 ($M).0.1">$215,356</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="ranking-slide brand-revenue-slide" data-reactid=".16d1cbmhnfi.1.0.4.1:1.3.1.0.0.0.$slide-Morning Consult Brand Index" style="transform:translateX(0px);-webkit-transform:translateX(0px);">
        <a class="ranking-caption" data-reactid=".16d1cbmhnfi.1.0.4.1:1.3.1.0.0.0.$slide-Morning Consult Brand Index.0" href="https://morningconsultintelligence.com/examine?v=YnJhbmRzX3RyZW5kX3dhbG1hcnQ&amp;d=dHNkYXQ&amp;s=bW9ybmluZyBjb25zdWx0&amp;ref=Zm9ydHVuZQ"><span class="title" data-reactid=".16d1cbmhnfi.1.0.4.1:1.3.1.0.0.0.$slide-Morning Consult Brand Index.0.0">Morning Consult Brand Index</span><span class="data" data-reactid=".16d1cbmhnfi.1.0.4.1:1.3.1.0.0.0.$slide-Morning Consult Brand Index.0.1">A-</span></a><a class="morning-consultant" data-reactid=".16d1cbmhnfi.1.0.4.1:1.3.1.0.0.0.$slide-Morning Consult Brand Index.1" href="javascript:void(0)"><svg data-reactid=".16d1cbmhnfi.1.0.4.1:1.3.1.0.0.0.$slide-Morning Consult Brand Index.1.0" height="19" viewbox="0 0 19 19" width="19">
        <path d="M17.153 9.368c0 4.293-3.492 7.785-7.785 7.785-4.292 0-7.785-3.492-7.785-7.785 0-4.292 3.493-7.785 7.785-7.785 4.293 0 7.785 3.493 7.785 7.785M19 9.5C19 4.262 14.738 0 9.5 0S0 4.262 0 9.5 4.262 19 9.5 19 19 14.738 19 9.5m-7.96-4.005c.195-.196.307-.468.307-.745 0-.28-.112-.55-.308-.747-.197-.197-.47-.31-.748-.31-.277 0-.55.113-.746.31-.198.196-.31.468-.31.747 0 .277.112.55.31.745.197.197.467.31.746.31.278 0 .55-.113.747-.31m-2.044 9.81c-.164 0-.326-.054-.458-.16-.21-.17-.31-.44-.26-.705l1.03-5.184-.567.317c-.35.196-.796.072-.993-.277-.198-.35-.074-.79.277-.988l1.947-1.09c.25-.14.556-.12.787.045.23.166.343.45.288.728L9.98 13.363l.873-.378c.37-.16.8.008.96.375.162.367-.007.794-.377.954l-2.15.93c-.093.042-.192.062-.29.062" data-reactid=".16d1cbmhnfi.1.0.4.1:1.3.1.0.0.0.$slide-Morning Consult Brand Index.1.0.0" fill="#1BAAE1"></path></svg></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

That data fully represents the webpage content you are asking about:

[image: webpage element]

Comment: @ba_ul have you checked that?